# Preview Image before submit with rails, stimulus rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I stuck in this problem
in my html code i code like this

```
<div class="form-outline mb-4 w-100" data-controller="preview-upload">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <%= form.label :images %>
          <%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 preview-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

all i want when i upload a file or multi files, it will render a image tag inside the

```
<div class="col-12 preview-image"></div>
```

and has a button delete, when click this button it will remove this image and update the input field.
How can i specific this in stimulus controller